# Запись в масив масивов

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть массив массивов, создан таким образом

```
Array array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int[]), 10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     array.SetValue(Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10), i);
```

Как мне записать данные в него ?

Comment: используй `.SetValue`

Comment: Я не могу обратиться к вложенному массиву. А стандартное обращение SetValue не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так

`((Array)array.GetValue(0)).SetValue(10,3);`

Но зачем через такие мудреные конструкции, если можно так?

```
 var array = new int[10][];
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     array[i] = new int[10];

 array[0][3] = 10;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Знаю что такая конструкция удобней но стояла задача использовать массив Array.